# Unable to install curl on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, curl

I am trying to install Curl on Debian but unfortunately I get the following error:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1) but 7.38.0-4+deb8u2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I tried to solve that by using: `sudo apt-get autoremove` as another thread suggested it but I keep having the same issue.

How can I solve that ?

**Edit:**

Here's the output of `apt-cache policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://mirrors.online.net/debian/ jessie/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://mirrors.online.net/debian/ jessie/main Translation-en
 500 http://mirrors.online.net/debian/ jessie/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://mirrors.online.net/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=8.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin mirrors.online.net
 500 http://mirrors.online.net/debian/ jessie/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=8.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin mirrors.online.net
 500 http://mirrors.online.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin mirrors.online.net
Pinned packages:
     nginx -> 1.10.0-1
```

And here's the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb http://mirrors.online.net/debian jessie main

deb http://mirrors.online.net/debian jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.online.net/debian jessie main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy`?

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` too.

Comment: @StephenKitt I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

The `libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1)` package come from `testing` and it is installed ,to fix `curl`'s dependencies you need to downgrade [libcurl3-gnutls](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libcurl3-gnutls) version from `7.47` to `7.38` using `aptitude` (because it's more helpful than `apt-get`) .

Open the terminal and type the following command :

```
sudo aptitude -f install libcurl3-gnutls
```

Follow the instructions and choose to downgrade the package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer GAD3R !
Aptitude didn't gave me the option to just downgrade libcurl3-gnutls so i deleted it with `sudo apt-get remove libcurl3-gnutls` and then I installed the version needed by curl (7.38.0-4+deb8u3).

Answer (score -1):

Simply, you need to upgrade it and then install curl again.

sudo apt-get -f upgrade.

then

sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl

Comment: `libcurl3 has not candidates to install` - What damn?!